# "I come from France"

Tags: subjects, objects

Is "France" the direct object in the sentence?

"I" is doing the verb "come" but is France receiving the verb? The grammar book says that direct object answers **who** or **what** questions but France does not so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Some verbs are transitive, and others are intransitive.  (Many verbs can be either, depending how they are used.)

A transitive verb takes a direct object.  In a sentence like "I love France" or "I am leaving France", "France" is the direct object.

An intransitive verb doesn't take a direct object.  "Come" is intransitive.  You can say "I am coming" on its own, without anything else.  The sentence "I come from France" has no direct object.  "From France" is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The part of this sentence, "from France" is a prepositional phrase that consists of the preposition "from" and its object "France".

"I" is the SUBJECT of this sentence and as your book says, answers the question "who?"  Who came from France?  "I" did.

Comment: So which part is the subject?

Comment: "I" is the subject of the verb "come".